Docker: Error response from daemon: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (createSnapDevice) dm_task_run failed
I am trying to load an image but encountered an error:
[root@git Gitlab_upgrade_DONTDELETE]# docker load -i gitlab16115.tar
Error response from daemon: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (createSnapDevice) dm_task_run failed
[root@git Gitlab_upgrade_DONTDELETE]#
This is my docker info:
Containers: 3
Running: 2
Paused: 0
Stopped: 1
Images: 35
Server Version: 1.10.3
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Name: docker-253:2-100663488-pool
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
Backing Filesystem: xfs
Data file: /dev/loop0
Metadata file: /dev/loop1
Data Space Used: 80.15 GB
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
Data Space Available: 27.22 GB
Metadata Space Used: 74.32 MB
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
Metadata Space Available: 2.073 GB
Udev Sync Supported: true
Deferred Removal Enabled: false
Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
Data loop file: /apps/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev or use --storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true to suppress this warning.
Metadata loop file: /apps/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
Library Version: 1.02.170-RHEL7 (2020-03-24)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: overlay bridge null host
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.114.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: JBoss
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 11.58 GiB
Name: git
ID: Q2L2:KKYE:B4JX:QKGU:Y24H:PXTN:DG3K:DWMQ:XS6F:4OFX:EYNH:T324
Cluster store: consul://docker.mng:8500/network
Cluster advertise: 10.10.180.6:2375
I have tried to do the suggestion on other sites:
1)service docker stop

thin_check /home/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata

thin_check --clear-needs-check-flag     /home/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata

service docker start


but there is no folder devicemapper inside /home/docker. Can you please assist us.
Thanks!
